# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I add [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "ADMIN")]

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a method in service

```
  [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "ADMIN")]
  public UserInfo GetUserInfo(string login, string password)
  {
     logger.Debug("Getting User Info");
     return new UserInfo() {Balance = 100, UserName = "User1"};
  }
```

When I add `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "ADMIN")]` I start getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception.

The code used in project:

```
public class AuthorizationPolicy: IAuthorizationPolicy
{

  Guid _id = Guid.NewGuid();
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  // this method gets called after the authentication stage
  public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
  {
     logger.Debug("Evaluate");
     // get the authenticated client identity
     IIdentity client = GetClientIdentity(evaluationContext);
     // set the custom principal
     evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = new CustomPrincipal(client);
     logger.Debug("Evaluate end");
     return true;
  }

  public ClaimSet Issuer { get; private set; }

  private IIdentity GetClientIdentity(EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
  {
     logger.Debug("GetClientIdentity");
     object obj;
     if (!evaluationContext.Properties.TryGetValue("Identities", out obj))
        throw new Exception("No Identity found");
     IList<IIdentity> identities = obj as IList<IIdentity>;
     if (identities == null || identities.Count <= 0)
        throw new Exception("No Identity found");
     logger.Debug("GetClientIdentity end");
     return identities[0];
  }

  public string Id { get { return _id.ToString(); }
     private set { }
  }
```

}

And web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>

          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
            <authorizationPolicies>
              <add policyType="Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy, App_Code/Security" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
          </serviceAuthorization>
          <!--Specify the Custom Authentication policy that will be used and add the policy location-->
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                    customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Beleke.UserAuthentication,Beleke"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Beleke.BelekeService" behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="http://userpc.ktcorp.local/WCFVW/BelekeService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          contract="Beleke.IBelekeService"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceBinding">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Server stack trace:

```
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at TestMyService.ServiceReference1.IBelekeService.GetUserInfo(String login, String password)
   at TestMyService.ServiceReference1.BelekeServiceClient.GetUserInfo(String login, String password) in d:\beleke\branches\master\TestMyService\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 213
   at TestMyService.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\beleke\branches\master\TestMyService\Program.cs:line 39
```

**UPDATE**

The trace file contains:

```
    2014-02-27 18:48:35.2164|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|Evaluate
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2164|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|GetClientIdentity
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2164|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|GetClientIdentity end
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2164|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|Evaluate end
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2164|DEBUG|Beleke.BelekeService|Changing balance
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2694|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|Evaluate
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2694|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|GetClientIdentity
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2694|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|GetClientIdentity end
2014-02-27 18:48:35.2694|DEBUG|Beleke.Security.AuthorizationPolicy|Evaluate end
```

And this is server-side trace

```
at System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission.Demand()
at System.Security.PermissionSet.DemandNonCAS()
at Beleke.BelekeService.GetUserInfo(String login, String password) in d:\beleke\branches\master\BelekeService\App_Code\BelekeService.cs:line 29
at SyncInvokeGetUserInfo(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
```

Comment: The stacktrace you provided is the one where your exception has been rethrown client side. The NullReferenceException does not occurs there, but in your code server side. Can you attach your VS to your IIS process, or whatever exe that is hosting your server ?

Comment: And since you are logging, perhaps show us those logs too?

Comment: `BelekeService.cs:line 29` could you show us this line?

Comment: `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "ADMIN")]
      public UserInfo GetUserInfo(string login, string password)
      
{`

Comment: Damn, I cant format the comment properly. But line 29 is the opening brace

Comment: I looked at uncompiled code in PrincipalPermission.Demand()... the only thing that seems to be potentially null is your IPrincipal.Identity. It seems that you're using "CustomPrincipal" ... are you sure that its Identity property is not returning null ?

Comment: If not, the IL offset at which this exception occurs would be usefull :)

Comment: @Oliver, you got the bounty )

Comment: For some reason I have my Windows username in _identity.Name, and not the client username I set in client program code....

Comment: Cool :) Let me create an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment:

I looked at uncompiled code in PrincipalPermission.Demand()

The only thing that seems to be potentially null is your IPrincipal.Identity.

It seems that you're using "CustomPrincipal" ... are you sure that its Identity property is not returning null ?

**Bonus**

Uncompiled code:

```
public void Demand()
{
  new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlPrincipal).Assert();
  IPrincipal currentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
  if (currentPrincipal == null)
    this.ThrowSecurityException();
  if (this.m_array == null)
    return;
  int length = this.m_array.Length;
  bool flag = false;
  for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
  {
    if (this.m_array[index].m_authenticated)
    {
      IIdentity identity = currentPrincipal.Identity;
      if (identity.IsAuthenticated && (this.m_array[index].m_id == null || string.Compare(identity.Name, this.m_array[index].m_id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
      {
        if (this.m_array[index].m_role == null)
        {
          flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
          WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = currentPrincipal as WindowsPrincipal;
          flag = windowsPrincipal == null || !(this.m_array[index].Sid != (SecurityIdentifier) null) ? currentPrincipal.IsInRole(this.m_array[index].m_role) : windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(this.m_array[index].Sid);
        }
        if (flag)
          break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (flag)
    return;
  this.ThrowSecurityException();
}
```

Comment: Can't award the bounty yet - SO requires to wait. So, now I've got another problem. My `_identity.Name` containt windows username, instead of credentials I set via `proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";` any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Where is _identity ? How is it assigned ?

Comment: @Oliver, ah, thought I had that part posted.... So, there is  `public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)` part, and the evaluationContext I receive here contains Windows Username.

Comment: No idea :/ I guess the issue is client side... try to set a breakpoint in UserName setter ? (Not your code, thus: Debug->New breakpoint->Break at function:  UserNamePasswordClientCredential.set_UserName )

Comment: Solved it - misconfiguration. I added the binding, but didn't mention binding's name in "bindingConfiguration" tag.